vercel doesn't render an image properly
i deployed my app to vercel, using nextjs and tailwind.
here i have a navbar, and as a bottom border of nav i need to use image as a border instead of normal border created with css.
Here's how it looks on localhost:

and that's how it looks in vercel:

in the console in both localhost and vercel i'm getting the same error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
if you need the code, here's implementaion of border bottom as an image:
*navbar*

<div className="relative">
        <Image
          src="/assets/images/navUnderline.png"
          alt="navbar underline"
          width={10}
          height={10}
          className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full -z-10" // Full width and positioned at the bottom
        />
</div>

an image contains in public folder

i have fixed it. So apparently vercel didn't like this image as PNG, so after i turned it into SVG this vercel bug has been fixed
